# Python import XXXXX as XX vs from XXXXX import *

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I feel like this is one of those questions that there's something I need to learn before I ask a question that makes sense, yet here we are.

So what's the difference with the code below? I understand the syntaxes changes but anything else? Is it just a matter of preference or what?

example 1:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
myLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Automation Panel")

myLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

example 2:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = tk()
mLabel = Label(root, text="Automation Panel")

myLabel.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `. . . import *` in the majority of cases. It "dumps" all available names from the module into your current namespace; "polluting" it.

Say you have a module `your_module.py`:

```
def func():
    pass
```

Then you do:

```
from your_module import *

def func():  # Name collision!
    pass
```

Now there are two `func`s here, the one imported, and the one you defined. Your definition will shadow the imported name though, so it won't be accessible.

Compare that to:

```
import your_module as ym

def func():  # No name collision
    pass
```

Since the `your_module.func` is tucked inside `ym`, both `ym.func` and `func` will be accessible.

Comment: Okay, that actually makes a lot of sense.